# Phonegap: how to show the cursor in a readonly textarea

Tags: cordova, cursor, textarea, readonly

I am working on a project where I need to display the cursor in a text area that is readonly.

Can someone help me on this one?

Thanks

Comment: In your javascript you could call something like `document.getElementById("mytextarea").focus()` The textfield then will have a cursor although it is readonly

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I tried it but it didnt work for me.